# Unicode in Django Messages Framework

Tags: django, unicode

I have a flash message in Django that is built using a standard char field from a memberships model.

```
messages.add_message(request,
                     messages.INFO,
                     '{0} membership created'.format(membership.name))
```

This works just fine unless `memberships.name` contains unicode characters in which case I get a `UnicodeEncodeError`. I can fix this by prepending the string with `u` to create a unicode string but I don't understand why this is necessary as the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/unicode/#general-string-handling) state that Django assumes all bytestrings are in UTF-8. Should I be going through my app and changing all strings to unicode strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an issue with Django. It looks like you're being caught out by a bug in the way `str.format` handles unicode arguments, [Python Issue 7300](http://bugs.python.org/issue7300)

One workaround is to use a unicode string, another is to use `%` formatting.

```
'%s membership created' % membership.name
u'{0} membership created'.format(membership.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
Except those that are actually byte-strings because they were read from a file or so.

Comment: Or try "from __future__ import unicode_literals". And of course, read Spolskys article about Unicode everyone should read.

Comment: I've read Spolsky's article in the past but it's always worth a refresh, thanks.